# perl using signals between applications

Tags: perl, signals

I would like to send events between applications. I have seen in Event::Lib there is functionality for handling interprocess signals. My question is what signal I should use? I guess I would need some user-defined signal. I don't know if that is available. I'm an ex-MS c++ programmer moving to unix and perl. I'm not married to that module or using signals so if another module or technique has what I need that would be okay.

Comment: That's the subject of IPC, Inter-Process-Communication, and there are a number of ways for two "things" to communicate. What kind of information would they need to exchange?  What are those "applications" -- independent programs?

Comment: In short, on *nix you can use actual signals (sent using [kill](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) and caught by installing a simple "handler"), and there are `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` for "free" use (see signal(7) man page).  I don't know on OS/X but I'd imagine that they are available.  However, that doesn't allow you to "say" much -- it's really just a signal.  Is that enough for your needs?

Comment: Do you want to send signals or events, because those are different things. What's the target and what do you want to instruct it to do?

Comment: @zdim Worth adding that the permission model for UNIX signals is very limited, signals can only be sent to processes owned by the same user (with the exception of `root`).